# For loop and rolling average in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, pandas-groupby

```
print(df)

    concatted  score       date status  apple  banana  orange
0  apple_bana  0.500 2010-02-20   high   True   False   False
1       apple  0.400 2010-02-10   high   True   False   False
2      banana  0.530 2010-01-12   high  False    True   False
3        kiwi  0.532 2010-03-03    low  False   False   False
4        cake  0.634 2010-03-05    low  False   False   False
```

In general code, how could I do a forloop for each fruit that:

1. only keep rows that have True under that fruit's column; and then:
2. gen a column for that fruit's  7_day rolling average based on their score
3. gen a column for that fruit's 7_day rolling average based on the proportion that has status 'high'

Each fruit should have 2 columns added: e.g. 'apple_score_7_day_roll' and  'apple_pct_7_day_roll'

New to python, my attempt:

```
for fruit in fruits:
    df = df[{0}].format[fruits]
    g = df.groupby('date')[fruit]
    df['fruit_7_day_roll'] = g['score'].rolling(7, min_periods=1).mean()

    g['high_status'] = g.apply(lambda x: x[x['status'] == 'High'].count())
    g['total'] = g.apply(lambda x: x[x].count())
    df['fruit_pct_7_day_roll'] = g['high_status']/g['total'].rolling(7, min_periods=1).mean()
```

Comment: Does your current solution work? If yes, what are you trying to achieve? You might also want to add a bit more data in your example, and let us know what the expected outcome is.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, trying to get 2 columns generated for the rolling averages for each fruit

Comment: Showing your expected output df based on this example would be helpful to illustrate exactly what you need.